# VBA ComboBox Time - Opposite to others

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

My UserForm has a combobox which is supposed to show Time. I have added 4 rows containing hours in one of the 3 sheets in the workbook.

Sheet1 was named EE Data, Rows = P1:P4, Format = Time. This range has been named as TZ using name manager.

I have searched and was able to found that people had issue with combobox showing time in decimal after selecting it from the drop down. My problem is opposite to that i.e. Drop down list shows time in decimal and not like what it is in source on excel sheet. Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
Private Sub PR()                                           
Dim cLoc As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("EE Data")
 For Each cLoc In ws.Range("TZ")
 With UserForm1.ComboBox1
 .AddItem cLoc.Value
  End With
 Next cLoc
 End Sub
```

Thanks!

P1 is 8:30 AM
P2 is 9:00 AM
P3 is 10:00 AM
P4 is 11:00 AM

[TimeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmUo.jpg)

Comment: `Drop down list shows time in decimal and not like what it is in source on excel sheet`  ... please post an example of each

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my combobox and mentioned the hours in each cell to my original question. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto the properties of Combobox and set Property "Row Source" to "TZ"(Your name of Range).

Comment: I have tried it now. It's working fine even when Sheet is hidden.